# Docker с контейнером nginx не открывается сайт

Tags: nginx, docker

Всем привет! Помогите пожалуйста настроить рабочую среду с использованием докера. Перелопатил русский и английский SO, но не нашел подходящего решения. Я пробую сделать среду для разработки с использованием Docker, nginx, php, mysql. На хосте Ubuntu 18.04. Ввожу

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
```

Nginx, php, mysql запускаются, работают, но сайт в браузере не открывается. Запрос уходит, но в ответ совсем ничего нет. Браузер пишет "Хмм. Нам не удаётся найти этот сайт." И не понятно где проблема, с сетью между хостом и докером или с настройками docker-compose.yml. docker-compose.yml вот такого содержания:

```
    version: '3.7'
    services:
        nginx:
            image: nginx:1.12
            restart: always
            ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "4430:443"
            expose: 
            - "80"
            networks:
            - bridge
            volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
            tty: true
            command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
        php:
            build: ./images/php
            volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
            expose:
            - "9000"
            networks:
            - bridge
        mysql:
            image: mysql:5.7
            volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            expose:
            - "3306"
            networks:
            - bridge
            environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=devbd
            - MYSQL_USER=devuser
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
networks:
  bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

Конфиг nginx имеет такой вид:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name dev-php.local *.dev-php.local;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php index.html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev-php-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/dev-php-access.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass php:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Dockerfile для образа php:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \ 
# RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Answer (score 1):

В данной конфигурации у вас клиент (браузер) стучится по-умолчанию в 80 порт, который у вас закрыт. Директива `expose` открывает порт лишь по внутренней сети (для связанных служб), т.е. для php и mysql в вашем случае.

Чтобы всё заработало откройте в браузере `localhost:8080` (у вас он в docker-compose файле пропрошен на 80 порт nginx контейнера), либо в `ports` nginx добавьте `80:80`. Для HTTPS соединения соотвественно либо `localhost:4430`, либо в `ports` 443:443

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но для  nginx у меня  указано ports:
            - "8080:80"
Попробовал зайти через localhost:8080, пишет "Попытка соединения не удалась". Также если зайти по IP контейнера nginx 172.22.0.4:8080 (он пингуется)

Comment: @websf у вас nginx слушает хост dev-php.local и *.dev-php.local. А вы ему посылаете хост localhost или IP. Поэтому попробуйте на своем хосте на Ubuntu добавить в файл /etc/hosts `dev-php.local 127.0.0.1` или же в nginx измените хост на localhost

Comment: docker ps выдает вот это 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4430 для nginx
Вроде как получается любой адрес. Этот /etc/hosts dev-php.local 127.0.0.1 попробовал. Не идет.

Comment: Проблема решилась, неправильное расширение файла конфига nginx было. Было test-site.config подсказали что нужно сделать default.conf и должно подхватиться, сделал, заработало.